# Homebrew script to reinstall formulas

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, homebrew

I'd like to develop a bash script to capture the currently installed Homebrew formula, then be able to reinstall these formulas in the event that I need to reinstall my OS.

I'm hoping to combine these two segments into a single, parametrized script:

Capture currently-installed formulas:

```
#!/bin/sh

# capture
brew list >> ~/sh.brew.formulas.txt
```

Install Homebrew and formulas:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

# get most-recent list of formulas
brew update

# disable macports
# TODO

# process list of formulas that have been installed
for i in $(cat ~/sh.brew.formulas.txt) ; do
  brew install $i
done
```

Then call it:

```
$ ./brewer.sh archive

$ ./brewer.sh install
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own problem by learning more about Bash scripting.

The result is [`brewer` project](https://github.com/craibuc/brewer).

> Bash script to archive or restore a workstation's Homebrew formulas.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author:   Craig Buchanan

# Purpose:  Archive currently installed Homebrew formulas to allow them to be reinstalled after a OS failure

# Revision History:
    # 31-OCT-2014 - created
    # 07-NOV-2014 - command-line parameter support

# Enhancements:
# * Homebrew Cask support?

# Reset POSIX variable in case getopts has been used previously in the shell.
OPTIND=1

# Initialize variables:
FORMULAS=~/sh.brew.formulas.txt
verbose=0
show_help=0

#
# heredocs
#
GENERAL_HELP=$(cat << 'EOF'

Usage:

  brewer [options] command

Exmaples:

  brewer archive
  brewer install

Options:

  -h     Display help
  -v     Enable verbose output

EOF)

ARCHIVE_HELP=$(cat << 'EOF'

Usage:

  brewer [options] archive

Exmaples:

  brewer archive
  brewer -f PATH/TO/FILE archive

Options:

  -f     file to use as destination (default: $FORMULAS)


EOF)

INSTALL_HELP=$(cat << 'EOF'

Usage:

  brewer [options] install

Exmaples:

  brewer install
  brewer -f PATH/TO/FILE install

Options:

  -f     file to use as source (default: $FORMULAS)

EOF)

#
# Save list of install Homebrew formulas to a file.
#
function archive() {

    if [ $show_help -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "$ARCHIVE_HELP\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then    
        echo "Archiving current list of Homebrew formulas ..."
    fi

    # make back-up current file if it exists
    if [ -f $FORMULAS ]; then

        if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
        then
            echo "Copying existing archive to $(basename $FORMULAS .txt)_$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S").txt ..."
        fi
        mv "$FORMULAS" "$(basename $FORMULAS .txt)_$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%Y%m%dT%H%M%S").txt"
    fi

    # redirect command to a file
    brew list >> $FORMULAS

    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "$FORMULAS created."
    fi

}

#
# Install Homebrew, then install formulas.
#
function install() {

    if [ $show_help -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "$INSTALL_HELP\n"
        exit 1
    fi

    # if $FILE doesn't exist, fail
    if [ ! -f $FORMULAS ];
    then
        if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
        then
            echo "$FORMULAS does not exist.  Please run './brewer archive' to create it."
        fi
       exit 2
    fi

    # if Homebrew not installed, install it
    type -P brew &>/dev/null && echo "Homebrew found ..." || {

        echo "Installing Homebrew ..."
        ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

    }

    # get most-recent list of formulas
    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "Updating Homebrew ..."
    fi
    brew update

    # TODO: disable macports
    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "Disabling Macports ..."
    fi

    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "Installing formulas..."
    fi

    # process list of formulas that have been installed
    # ignoring lines that start with an '#'
    for i in $( sed '/^#/ d' < "$FORMULAS") ; do

        if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
        then
            echo "Installing $i ..."
        fi

        # attempt to install formula
        # if error (e.g. alread installed), write error, process next formula
        brew install $i || continue

    done

    if [ $verbose -eq 1 ]; 
    then
        echo "Processing completed."
    fi
}

#
# Process command line
#
while getopts "h?vf:" opt; do

    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        show_help=1
        ;;
    v)  verbose=1
        ;;
    f)  FILE=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

shift $((OPTIND-1))

[ "$1" = "--" ] && shift

# echo "verbose=$verbose, show_help=$show_help, FILE='$FILE', Leftovers: $@"

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "$GENERAL_HELP\n"
    exit 1
fi

# run command
$1
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you described what the exact problem was and how you solved i.